# Ionic build with docker and jenkins

Tags: macos, docker, jenkins, ionic-framework, docker-machine

I am new to docker and I want to have the ionic environment/build dockerized. I have some steps in mind however for me it is not clear if I can run any xcode command in Docker.

Steps:
- Docker container with jenkins
- Run a build for ios with jenkins job if I am in a MacOS machine running Docker for MacOS (I heared that it is different from boot2docker but I have not tried yet)
- Docker container with android environment
- Run a build for android with jenkins job

Any suggestions?